# AMP add a image on base64

Tags: image, base64, amp-html

Hi im using amp when i add a image on base64 i cant see the image, this is how it amp print:

```
<img alt="metallica" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

i try to add amp-image and amp-iframe but it doesn't work

could you please help me

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have tried using the  tag.
Kindly refer the following URL, where the same issue is addressed.
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/538#issuecomment-146822062

Hope this helps. Ensure that you are using all the valid and required tags.
Still if you are not able to solve, then do post the URL of your page of exact HTML code, so that we get clear idea of the issue